# Wrong date format with toLocaleString on server side

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Using this on a server side (a Firebase function, `nodejs` )

```
   var d=new Date();
   var date = d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long'}) + ", " + d.getFullYear();
```

I am expecting to get `March, 2020` , since this is what i get on the `JS` client side, **but instead when run on the server side i get - M03, 2020** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code:

```
const date = require('date-and-time');

var d = new Date();

var myDate = d.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long'}) + ", " + d.getFullYear();

console.log(myDate);
```

Output:

```
March, 2020
```

---

Now, if you are trying to store a Javascript `Date` object into Firebase, this object will be stored as a `Timestamp` object. I think this would explain the reason why you are noticing some discrepancies in the format.

Optionally, you can convert the `Date` object to `String` and store it in Firebase as such. This is more human-readable than [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and [Timestamp - 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp)

You can read more about this in the following documentation about [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) and [Data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types). Moreover, there exists a `Timestamp` built-in method `toDate()` that returns a new Date corresponding to a certain timestamp, if conversion is needed.